# Starting with administering a linux box

Tags: mysql, domain, lamp

I'm rather new to this, and I'd like to play with administering a linux box.

Things I need to know how to do:

- Setup subdomains
- Setup FTP accounts
- Setup full domains / add domains
- MySQL setup / install / management
- LAMP setup / install / management

This is probably going on a CentOS distro. I'd like links or a break down on how I can learn to do this. I am comfortable with a command line, but I'm trying to move from shared hosting to a VPS and would like to have some idea on how deep the water is before I do.

Comment: Well... install VirtualBox, download Centos, see the docs listed below, and have at it. Also take a look a programs like Puppet/Chef/etc. if you want to automate some of that administration.

Answer (score 3):

[RUTE](http://rute.2038bug.com/index.html.gz)

[RHEL docs](http://www.redhat.com/docs/manuals/enterprise/)

That'll get you most of the way there. Make sure you find a box that you don't mind nuking and reinstalling on, because the best way of getting a handle on it is destroying it a few times.

Comment: The worst possible thing that can happen when learning is that everything goes according to plan.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of good stuff at howtoforge as well.

LINK: [HERE](http://www.howtoforge.com/howtos/linux/centos)

Comment: Be careful with HTF though. Some of their instructions are... suspect, and without the proper knowledge already in place it's hard to know what to avoid doing.

Comment: @Ignacio, very true. I generally use them as a template for process rather than as a step-by-step tutorial.